# Find Max Number(s) in an ArrayList (Possibility of More Than One Max Value)

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to find the index/indices that hold the maximum value in an `ArrayList`. I want to preserve the order that the numbers are in (in other words no sorting) because I want to keep track of what index had what value. The values are from a random number generator and there is the possibility of having two (or more) indices sharing the same maximum value.

An example `ArrayList`:

> 12, 78, 45, 78
>
> 0,1,2,3 <- indices

(So indices, 1 and 3 contain the values that have the max values. I want to maintain the fact that indices 1 and 3 have the value 78. I do not want to just create a new `ArrayList` and have indices 0 and 1 of the new `ArrayList` have the values 78)

Therefore, I want to find all of the indices that have the maximum values because I will be doing something with them to "break" the tie if there is more than one index. So how can I find the indices that contain the maximum value and maintain the index-to-value relationship?

I have written the following methods:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> maxIndices(ArrayList<Integer> numArrayList) {
// ???  
    return numArrayList;
}

public static void removeElement(ArrayList<Integer> numArrayList, int index) {
    numArrayList.remove(index);
}

public static int getMaxValue(ArrayList<Integer> numArrayList) {
    int maxValue = Collections.max(numArrayList);
    return maxValue;
}

public static int getIndexOfMaxValue(ArrayList<Integer> numArrayList, int maxVal) {
    int index = numArrayList.indexOf(maxVal);
    return index;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've basically not written any code to do the requested task. [What _have_ you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Matt Ball It is the reason why I am asking. I need help in how to do it. I have considered hashing...

Comment: get out of the habit of declaring things as ArrayList<?> if it must be a List then declare it as a List.

Comment: @BevynQ I do not want a List. I want an ArrayList, so I do not understand your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> maxIndices(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int max =  getMaxValue(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       if(list.get(i) == max) {
           indices.add(list.get(i));
        }
     }

     return indices;
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it is adding the value of the current index if it is the maximum? So if I wanted just the index itself that has the max value then I would just do: `indices.add(i);`?

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's supposed to be indices.add(i) instead of indices.add(list.get(i))

Answer (score 1):

O(n) solution:

```
   public static List<Integer> maxIndices(List<Integer> l) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer candidate = l.get(0);
        result.add(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < l.size(); i++) {
            if (l.get(i).compareTo(candidate) > 0) {
                candidate = l.get(i);
                result.clear();
                result.add(i);
            } else if (l.get(i).compareTo(candidate) == 0) {
                result.add(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```